# I am unable to click on a text field using id in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

[Here is the image of text field I want to click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMVLY.png)

This is the inspect field :

```
<input _ngcontent-oqh-c45="" formcontrolname="target" matinput="" placeholder="https://" class="mat-input-element mat-form-field-autofill-control ng-tns-c40-0 ng-untouched ng-pristine cdk-text-field-autofill-monitored ng-invalid" id="mat-input-0" data-placeholder="https://" aria-invalid="false" aria-required="false">
```

This is the code snippet I am using :

```
enter_url = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'mat-input-0')
enter_url.click()
```

This is the error I am getting :

```
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="mat-input-0"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=98.0.4758.102)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be because of three reasons

1. This is `mat-input-0`, especially the `0` part is dynamically generated.
2. The element is not rendered properly.
3. This field is in iframe or shadow-root.

Check for the below XPath:

```
//input[@formcontrolname = 'target' and @placeholder='https://' and starts-with(@id,'mat-input') and @aria-invalid='false']
```

if it's unique or not.

**Steps to check:**

`Press F12 in Chrome` -> go to `element` section -> do a `CTRL  + F` -> then paste the `xpath` and see, if your desired `element` is getting **highlighted** with `1/1` matching node.

1. If it is unique, then we can use explicit wait:

**Code:**

```
enter_url = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@formcontrolname = 'target' and @placeholder='https://' and starts-with(@id,'mat-input') and @aria-invalid='false']")))
enter_url.click()
```

**Imports:**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

2. If the XPath is not unique then we would need more HTML to locate the right element with uniqueness.

Comment: I checked the above xpath and it is unique also tried your code and got TimeoutException. Is it possible that websites can block text fields which we try to fill using automation?

Comment: Did you check for `This field is in iframe or shadow-root.` ?